# Clang static code analyze does not create .plist results for modules that is build with Android.bp

Tags: android, clang

Previously , I have implemented some modules under `android/packages/services/` with using Android.mk
and run clang static code analysis succesfully for this module , created .plist as the following:

```
from android/ path I exported WITH_STATIC_ANALYZER=1
```

and I tried to run

```
mmma packages/services/module_name
```

and all .plist are created under `android/` folder successfully.

Now, with same export flag, I have an issue while creating static code analyze results with clang for some modules that is added
inside `android/vendor/` module by me which is builded by using Android.bp file. When I run , `mmma vendor/module_name`, It does not create
any .plist.

I have added

```
cflags:[
"-Wall",
"-Werror",
"-Wunused",
"-Wunreachable-code",
],
```

in `cc_shared_library{}` , `cc_defaults{}` and `cc_binary{}` parts in Android.bp.Again no .plist nor any other format of static code analyze results.

Also, I have tried exporting, `WITH_TIDY=1` on `android/` but again no luck.

The AOSP version is Android P.

Is there any idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, I realized that when I add cflags to Android.bp, it is actually started to run the clang analyzer but it could not catch any errors that I created. When I add another intentional error, I got .plist file and it says  `Value stored to variable is never read`.

Before, this one I had added some memory leaks and could not get any warnings for that, so I created another question for it: 
[Clang analyzer missing memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844622/clang-analyzer-missing-memory-leaks)