# Clang analyzer missing memory leaks

Tags: android, c++, memory-leaks, clang-static-analyzer

I have issue while running clang on an android service on some cpp file.
I am creating an intentional memory leak by calling an object instance from
another class without deleting it to see if clang creates memory leak warning
or not but for some cases It is not creating memory leak warning.

1- If I put a class declaration in same header file with the class that I wanted to create a memory leak, clang catching the memory leak as the following:

## Example.h

```
 class Ad
 {
    public:
    void xx();
 };

 class Example
 {
    public:
    bool getData();
 };
```

## Example.cpp

```
#include "Example.h"

void Ad::xx()
{
    bool ar = false;
    ar = true;
}

bool Example::getData()
{
    char *ptrt;
    ptrt = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    snprintf(ptrt,10,"%s","trial");

    Ad *arr = new Ad();
    arr->xx();

    return true;
}
```

In this example, clang can catch 2 memory leaks in getData() function.

2-If I create class Ad declaration in separate header file than clang can not catch memory leak:

## Ad.h

```
class Ad
{
    public:
        void xx();
};
```

## Ad.cpp

```
#include "Ad.h"

void Ad::xx()
{
    bool ar = false;
    ar = true;
}
```

## Example.h

```
class Example
{
    public:
        bool getData();
};
```

## Example.cpp

```
 #include "Example.h"
 #include "Ad.h"

bool Example::getData()
{
    Ad *arr = new Ad();
    arr->xx();
    //Clang can not catch memory leak error here..
    return true;
}
```

`Notes:`

`I am exporting WITH_STATIC_ANALYZER=1 on aosp android/ folder`
`and running mmma module_name/ .`

`I am using Android P for aosp.`
`I also initialized this flags in Android.bp`

```
cflags:[
    "-Wall",
    "-Werror",
    "-Wunused",
    "-Wunreachable-code",
    ],
```

Is there any idea why that may happen ?

Comment: It's odd seeing C++ source file with the `.c` suffix, which is normally used for C source files.

Comment: There's also other things that are odd with the code you show, like using `malloc` instead of `new[]` (you should generally *never* use `malloc` in C++ code). And talking about `malloc`, you don't even include the header file that declares the function, which could lead to all sorts of *undefined behavior* unrelated to the memory leaks.

Comment: Maybe it catches the malloc() leak instead of the new() leak?

Comment: if you try the same thing on a plain linux (out of android) do you have the same problem?

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. They are cpp files I will edit my question

Comment: @RichardChang As I had written in the question, in the first case, it catches both new() and malloc().

Comment: I suggest trying more advanced tools of searching for errors. For example, the PVS-Studio analyzer reports about the memory leak: V773 [CWE-401] The function was exited without releasing the 'arr' pointer. A memory leak is possible. test1.cpp 45

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with clang's analyzer; however I think 2 things happen in the second case compared to the first:

1) When compiling, you're calling clang twice, creating 2 object files, each with one of the functions. Hence analyzer data cannot pass through from `Ad::xx` to `Example::getData`.

2) From the point of view of the Example.cpp clang invocation, nothing guarantees that `Ad::xx` does not store a reference to the `Ad` object on which it is called, thus its lifetime could be longer than the `Example::getData` scope. Hence no memory leak warning.

Try using the same input file for both implementations; that should make it work.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question(as in 1), when I put them into same file it gives the warnings but these implemetation is just a small sample of real code. Since real implementation is much larger, it will be better to separate them into two different input file.

Comment: A simple workaround: #include the implementations in a single file. Otherwise, this might be of interest: http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Clang-Static-Analyzer-Inter-File-Analysis-td4064341.html#a4064358

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I raised the question there also